# How can I search a string inside a string ? C

Tags: c, string, function, search

I'm programming in C. I'd like to search a string inside of a string.
Are there any built-in function that does that in string.h ? Or do you know how to create one ?

Comment: "string inside a string": strstr

Comment: Please have a look at http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node19.html which provides searching in string examples.

Comment: @Brandin actually that is a nice motto, string inside string is strstr

Comment: See e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr).

Comment: But what if you need to find a string inside a string INSIDE a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any built-in function that does that in string.h ?

Yes. Take a look at [`strstr()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989799/xsh/strstr.html), which is part of the standard library and declared in string.h.

Comment: But what it returns ?
As if I want to put it in an if().

Comment: Did you click the link? It *returns a pointer to the located string or a null pointer if the string is not found.* Specifically, it returns a `char *` that points to the first occurrence of the search string (`s2`) in the target string (`s1`).